# vim regex matching with Uppercase letters but NOT underscore

Tags: regex, vim

In vim regex syntax, I am trying to match with all words with starting uppercase, and not starting underscore

```
\\([A-Z][a-z_][A-Za-z_]\\+\\)
```

This is the what i have untill now.

I want something like this:

```
\\([A-Z^\_][a-z_][A-Za-z_]\\+\\)
```

Where `[A-Z^\\_]` denotes that it should match with all uppercase chars, but not underscore.

Any help would be greatly apreciated. Thanks in advance.

Edit: My question was woorded poorly. I want the first set to match with an uppercase char, which does not have an underscore in front of it. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[A-Z]` already does *not* include underscores; I guess you want to match **whole words**, so you don't want your regular expression to match *inside* a word. Vim has built-in `\<` and `\>` (like `\b` in other regular expression dialects, see @npinti's answer) for *keyword boundaries*; as lower/uppercase and underscore characters are usually keyword characters, wrapping your pattern with those should already be close enough:

```
\<\([A-Z][a-z_][A-Za-z_]\+\)\>
```

To strictly assert no underscore before your match (but allow any other keyword or non-keyword characters there), you'd need a *negative lookbehind*: `\@<!` means *is not preceded by*:

```
_\@<!\([A-Z][a-z_][A-Za-z_]\+\)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Where [A-Z^\_] denotes that it should match with all uppercase chars, but not underscore.

[A-Z] *already* matches with all uppercase chars excluding underscore. However in your first solution, you request that the *second* letter be lowercase or underscore (`[a-z_]`). If I stick to your definition:

> all words with starting uppercase, and not starting underscore

Then `[A-Z][A-Za-z_]+` should work.